# Make facebook icon reverse color when hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wanted to make a simple effect that can change Facebook icon image when hover.But instant my code did not return the effect I want. When I hover the image, it returns nothing. Here is my code. Can anyone teach me how to do? I accept answer in HTML, CSS or jquery.

**HTML**

```
<div class="loremipsum">
  <h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <p>We would love to here from you.So,just leave a email.</p>
  <div id="facebook-logo"><a href="http://facebook.com/joomgame"></a></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#facebook-logo{
    background:url('facebook-logo.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}

#facebook-logo:hover{
    background:url('facebook-logo-negative.png') no-repeat 0 -100px;
}
```

Comment: Why is there a `-100px`? Can you post the images also?

Comment: does facebook-logo-negative.png exist? and why you're using a background-position different than `0 0` ?

Comment: It's better for you to make a JSFiddle. However, it is a really bad idea to alter other company's logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have any content in a div, you need to set a `width` and `height` on it for it to appear :

```css
.picture {
  background-image: url('https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3016/3071708735_ddaf5d361b.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
}

.picture:hover {
  background-image: url('http://wallpaperscraft.com/image/29330/256x256.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="picture"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`#facebook-logo` needs a height and a width, since there is nothing to show inside it. Either place some text in it, or set the dimensions of `<a>` using CSS.

```
#facebook-logo {
    background:url('facebook-logo.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 100px; /* Otherwise it will extend to the whole width of the page */
}

/*
  This is better because you need to `click` on something. If you just set
  the dimensions of #facebook-logo, you still wouldn't be able to click on the link.
 */
#facebook-logo  a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

And make sure both the images exist.

```css
#facebook-logo {
  background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/uiconstock/socialmedia/128/Facebook-icon.png') no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 128px;
}
#facebook-logo a {
  display: block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
#facebook-logo:hover {
  background: url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wpzoom-developer-icon-set/500/01-128.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loremipsum">
  <h3>Contact Us</h3>
  <p>We would love to here from you.So,just leave a email.</p>
  <div id="facebook-logo">
    <a href="http://facebook.com/joomgame"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `#facebook-logo` div element `height` and `width` then background image show

```
#facebook-logo{
    background:url('facebook-logo.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 100px /*or whatever you need*/
    width: 100px /*or whatever you need*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the width and height of div then only you can put something on its background.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have those images on your site? (facebook-logo-negative.png and facebook-logo.png)

the code should be something like this if so:

background:url('img/facebook-logo.png') no-repeat 0 0;  (if the css file is on the same page as index.html)

and

background:url('../img/facebook-logo.png') no-repeat 0 0;  (if the css file is in another folder ex: css/style.css)

Also give the a width and height to that div.

Answer (score 0):

The others have already gave you the answers, but you might want to check this out.

Don’t

- Modify Facebook brand assets in any way, such as by changing the design or color

Source :https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts